# CMake GUI for CLion

Tags: clion

Is there a GUI for CMake (like `ccmake` or the CMake GUI application), integrated in CLion?

Instead of putting a CMake options string into Settings/CMake?

Answer (score 0):

Steps to accomplish what you want. I used this to see the variables. I imagine this works for editing them.

1. Find the cmake gui binary on your system or [Download Cmake](https://cmake.org/download/) and install it, which will give access but, make sure its the same version that CLION uses
2. Build your application or library in CLION using Cmake as normal to generate caches
3. For me on windows my cmake gui was in my start menu after installing it.
4. Follow these [directions](https://www.johnlamp.net/cmake-tutorial-3-gui-tool.html) ; basically setting the source and the build binaries, just use the existing project files. Then click on advanced to show your variables.

[image: CMAKE Gui Tool Sample]